# auto change font size when hitting width limit in css

Tags: css, html, fonts

Is it at all possible to make a font change size automaticly when its wider than the `<div>`?

I have tried a few methods but cant seem to find anything on-line regarding this

I have a box on my site the width of 250px and now and again there is a title longer than that it just over flows the div after or before it

and clues on this be great

Comment: possible duplicate of [Font scaling based on width of container](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056591/font-scaling-based-on-width-of-container)

Comment: do you know what i been search for ages for anything related to do with this thx ill have a look :)